# Adding & Subtracting Vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors

Question: Given $u = (2, 4, -3), v = (3, -1, 7),$ and $i, j, k$ being the standard basis vector, find:

$| v - u +3k |$

*My work*:

$ = |(3, -1, 7) - (2, 4, -3) + 3k |$

$ = |((3-2), (-1-4), 7 - (-3)) + 3k |$

$ = |(1, -5, 10) + 3k |$

*I know that the last line is not the full answer but I don't know what to do to continue to get the final result. I was thinking on making the coordinates $(1, -5, 10)$ into $i -5j +10k$ and then adding the $10k$ with the $3k$ to get $13k$ but I am still confused on what to do with the absolute expression afterwards. If anyone can help me out, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: The two vertical bars are instructing you to find the vector's magnitude. Most likely, the Euclidean norm which for a 3D vector is $|\mathbf{b}|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ where $\mathbf{b}=x_1\mathbf{ \hat{i}} + x_2 \mathbf{ \hat{j}} +x_3\mathbf{ \hat{k}}$. Do you understand what the magnitude represents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert $3k$ to the vector $(0,0,3)$.

$$|(1,-5,10)+(0,0,3)|=|(1,-5,13)|$$

Now, in case you weren't aware, the magnitude of a vector $|\vec{v}|$ is the distance between its two ends. This means that if we have a vector $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, then by Pythagoras's theorem we have $\vec{v}=\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2}$.

Using this definition we find the magnitude of $(1,-5,13)$ is

$$\sqrt{1^2+(-5)^2+13^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{1+25+169}$$
$$=\sqrt{195}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are right! Finish using this:
$$|ai+bj+ck| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$